# Flutter Blue Plus : PlatformException (PlatformException(setNotification, gatt.writeDescriptor() returned false, null, null))

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a problem using Flutter Blue plus. I have connected a device. and after that search for service(0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) and after that search characteristic (0000fff4-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) by after that await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);

After that there was a problem.
`await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);`

the following error
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(setNotification, gatt.writeDescriptor() returned false, null, null))

My Connect And Discover Notify value function

```
void connectToDevice() async {
    deviceConnectionSubscription = foundDevice?.state.listen((state) {
      if (state == BluetoothConnectionState.connected) {
        setState(() {
          isConnected = true;
        });
      } else if (state == BluetoothConnectionState.disconnected) {
        setState(() {
          isConnected = false;
        });
      }
    });
    var lock = new Lock();
    await foundDevice?.connect(autoConnect: true);
    List<BluetoothService>? services = await foundDevice?.discoverServices();
    if (services != null) {
      chr = services;
      print(services);
      if (services.isNotEmpty) {
        for (BluetoothService service in services) {
          if (service.uuid.toString() ==
              "0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") {
            List<BluetoothCharacteristic> characteristics =
                service.characteristics;
            for (BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic in characteristics) {
              if (characteristic.uuid.toString() ==
                  "0000fff4-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") {
                print("Characteristic found");

                await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);

                characteristic.value.listen((value) {
                  hexNumbere(value);
                });
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does the requested characteristic allow notifications? Have you checked using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?

Comment: Yes, "0000fff4-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" Notifiy is true

Comment: Someone had a similar problem last year: https://github.com/boskokg/flutter_blue_plus/issues/572
Unfortunately they did not mentioned how they fixed it. Maybe the suggestions from the others will help you?